# How to find the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} {2^n+(-1)^n \over 2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How do I find this limit?
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} {2^n+(-1)^n \over 2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}}$$
I don't know how to take the limit of $\lim_{n \to \infty}{(-1)^n}$, I know that the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} {2^n}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} {2^{n+1}}$ tend both to infinity.

I asked my teacher and he said that the solution was ${1 \over 2}$ but I don't know why, I tried to solve it but I got undefined as the answer, how do I solve this correctly?

When I did was $$\lim_{n \to \infty} {1+{(-1)^n\over2^n} \over 2+{(-1)^{n+1}\over2^n}}$$ I took the limit of that, and ended up like this:
$$ {1+\lim_{n \to \infty}{(-1)^n\over2^n} \over 2+\lim_{n \to \infty}{(-1)^{n+1}\over2^n}}$$ But both $\lim_{n \to \infty}{(-1)^{n}\over2^n}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}{(-1)^{n+1}\over2^n}$ gives me undefined, So I eneded up with $1+undefined\over2+undefined$

Comment: Try dividing top and bottom by $2^n$

Comment: Then I get $\lim_{n\to\infty} {1+{(-1)^n\over 2^n}\over2+{(-1)^{n+1}\over 2^n}}$ , but what happens with ${(-1)^n\over 2^n}$ and ${(-1)^{n+1}\over 2^n}$?

Comment: Do you know $ \lim_{n \to \infty} {\frac {1 + {1 \over 2^n }}  {2 + {1 \over 2^n}}}$ ?

Comment: I think it would be ${1 \over 2}$, right? Because $\lim_{n\to\infty} {1\over2^n}$ is 0.

Comment: Right, it would be $1 \over 2$

Comment: But I don't get it, how does the $(-1)^n$ and $(-1)^{n+1}$ become 1?

Comment: $(-1)^n$ does not "become" anything. Let $A_n=1+(-1)^n/2^n$ and $B_n=2+(-1)^n/2^{n+1}.$ Then $|A_n-1|=1/2^n$ and $ |B_n-2|=1/2^{n+1}.$ So $\lim_{n\to \infty} A_n=1$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}B_n=2.$ Therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty}A_n/B_n=(\lim_{n\to \infty}A_n)/(\lim_{n\to \infty}B_n)=1/2.$....

Comment: Re: My previous comment: The last sentence is valid only because $A_n$ and $B_n$ each have limits and because the limit of $B_n$ is not $0$.

Comment: $(-1)^n$ does not exist almost, then it goes to 1/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you divide the top and bottom by $2^n$, you get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1 + \frac{{(-1)}^n}{2^n}}{2 + \frac{{(-1)}^{n+1}}{2^n}}$$
Now seeing that both $\frac{{(-1)}^n}{2^n}$ and $\frac{{(-1)}^{n+1}}{2^n}$ approach $0$ as $x\to\infty$ (gotta use some intuition here), we get that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1 + \frac{{(-1)}^n}{2^n}}{2 + \frac{{(-1)}^{n+1}}{2^n}} = \frac{1+0}{2+0} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: But wouldn't $(-1)^n$ and $(-1)^{n+1}$ diverge? Because it is -1 and 1 if n is even or odd.

Comment: @davidllerenav We can write the two fractional sequences as $(-\frac{1}{2})^n$ and $-(-\frac{1}{2})^n$. Even though these sequences "bounce" back and forth between negative and positive, they still approach $0$.

Comment: Maybe you could make it more rigorous with the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)

Comment: @Hyperion That is because we write it like $({-1\over2})^n$ and $({-1\over2})^{n+1}$, right? Because I saw on my book that the $lim_{n\to\infty} a^n=0$ if |a|<1.

Comment: @davidllerenav Watch out on on your second fraction; $(-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1} \neq -(-\frac{1}{2})^{n}$, but other than that, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Then how would it be the second fraction reasoning?

Comment: You need to acquire some intuition. Make a table of the first few values of $\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2^n}$ and look at the numbers you get.

Answer (score 0):

$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ 2^n+(-1)^n }{ 2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1} } \\
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ \frac{2^n}{2^n} + \frac{{(-1)}^n}{2^n} }{ \frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n} + \frac{{(-1)}^{n+1}}{2^n} } \\
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ 1 + (\frac{-1}{2})^n }{ 2 - (\frac{-1}{2})^n } \\
= \frac{ 1 + \lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{-1}{2})^n }{ 2 - \lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{-1}{2})^n } \\ $

Using [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), and since $
-(\frac{1}{2})^n \le (\frac{-1}{2})^n \le (\frac{1}{2})^n \ \forall n \ge 1 $ and $
\lim_{n\to\infty} -(\frac{1}{2})^n = \lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{1}{2})^n = 0 $ , we get

$
= \frac{ 1 + 0 }{ 2 - 0 } \ [ \ \because \ \lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{-1}{2})^n = 0 \ ] \\
= \frac{1}{2}
$